# How can I load and access the Google Places library in a template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, laravel

I have a simple single-page application that implements the search box location prediction from Google but am now expanding it to the point where more than one page is required. To accomplish this, I am using angular's routing features for views. My parent template is index.php in the views directory of the laravel app `/app/views/index.php`. This loads all the components and styles(angular, bootstrap, fontawesome, jquery). Originally I was loading the Google Places library in my template file (index.html) as that was the only place it was used. As a side effect, I wasn't able to use angular controllers to perform the logic as I loaded the library with JavaScript in the html file. Now I'd like to include the library in my parent template so I can access the services and such from any page. Here is the working implementation with only one page:

index.html (child of index.php, inserted at ng-view, simplified)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX&libraries=places&callback=initGoogle" async defer></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initGoogle() {
            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService();
        }
    </script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

index.php (parent template, simplified)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- Bower Styles -->
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <!-- Bower Components -->
    <!-- Angular App -->

</body>
</html>
```

How can I move this library to the parent template (index.php) and use the services from my angular controllers? I thought by putting it in the parent's head block it would become "universally available" from any inheriting template so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend a parent layout, which can yield a section, that way you only load the google maps script when you need it.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, worked out very well. I would have kept it but I really wanted to leave as much of the front-end as possible to Angular and I knew Angular could do it, just had to figure it out. Either way, this answer and the one I posted using Angular below are both completely viable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think the reason it wasn't working originally for me was that I was loading the library in the body below the `ng-view` directive. By putting the script block in the head, it made the library accessible from child templates. I'm still not sure why this only didn't work for the google library and the others did not fail from being used before declaration. Either way, here is the solution:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <!-- Bower Styles -->
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <!-- Bower Components -->
    <!-- Angular App -->

    <!-- Google API Service: async and defer prevent initGoogle() being initialized until API is loaded -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX&libraries=places" async defer></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Initializing a service from controller:

```
Controllers.controller("Controller", [function() {

    var PlaceService;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        PlaceService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService();
    });

}]);
```

PlaceService can now be used inside the Controller. In addition, a service can be placed in a parent controller and accessed from children via `$scope.$parent.ServiceName`